# Lua game app required transition of object with scaling factor

Tags: lua, race-condition, coronasdk

I am working on a iOS Game Application (Race) which requires the background to have transition coming forward.

For the above requirement I have written a code where I have to make people feel as if the objects were coming from a far distance to nearby.

Hence I am using transition to do so where I increase their **y position** and scaling (both `xScale` and `yScale`). While doing so, the problem I am facing is when the objects seem to come closer with their size increasing (using **scaling**), the distance between the objects decreases from their actual distance because of scaling and it does not perfectly look as if the objects were coming from far behind.

Please let me know what is the best way to achieve what I trying to do or else if there is any available sample code having the functionality of car/bike racing.

Answer (score 0):

```
transition.to ( object,{  time=500, alpha=1,x = (destination x coor),y = (destination y coor),width =(to scale x),height =( to scale y), onComplete=saltCellarOnComplete}  )
```